# Ubercart: Store configuration for role based user

Tags: ubercart

I want these options such as show orders, sales report, product reports, customer reports,sales tax report which are available in store configuration of ubercart to be available for seller login(seller Role).

But for seller I want to show his orders alone like wise only related to his products all options. Is there a way for that?

Comment: No there's nothing like that built into Ubercart, you'd have to develop a solution yourself